# Issues with AR.js Location-Based Example from Documentation

Tags: javascript, gis, augmented-reality, geo, ar.js

I am trying to implement the location-based augmented reality functionality using AR.js library. I have been referring to the official AR.js documentation (https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/) and specifically the location-based section.

I have copied the provided code into my HTML file and made the necessary changes by replacing the add-your-latitude and add-your-longitude placeholders with my actual latitude and longitude values. However, the AR object is not appearing at the specified GPS coordinates. I have also tried adding multiple markers with close positions to my location, but still no success.

I have checked the browser console for any error messages, but there are no relevant errors or warnings. I have also ensured that my browser has location permission granted to the web page (I tested on iOS - safari and Chrome both).

Is there anyone who has successfully implemented the AR.js location-based functionality? Could there be any specific steps or considerations that I might be missing? Is there a working example or additional resources available for implementing location-based AR using AR.js?

I would appreciate any guidance or insights to help resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code works! You can try to add a position to your assets, including multiple assets and their position. The position is elevation from sea level.
You can try the following code.

```
<a-box material="color: blue" gps-entity-place="latitude: <>; longitude: <>" position="0 165 0" scale="3.5 3.5 3.5" rotation="0 180 0"> </a-box>
```

In the above example position tag gives 165m as elevation to the object on that GPS location.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I followed your instructions and tried the solution you provided, but unfortunately, it still doesn't seem to be working for me.
To give you more context, I'm using an iPhone 14 running iOS 16.5. I have tested the issue on both Safari and Chrome browsers, including incognito mode, but the problem persists (can't see any marker). I have deployed the project on both GitHub Pages and Netlify, but the error remains consistent across both platforms (don't think is related to this).
Could the problem be related to specific regions or locations?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
          document.querySelector('[gps-entity-place]').addEventListener('gps-entity-place-update-position', (payload) => {
            let v = parseInt(payload.detail.distance);
            alert(`${v} meter`);
            // you may show the distance in the value of <a-text>
            // document.getElementById("id-of-a-text").setAttribute('value', `${v} meter`);
          });
        })
    </script>
Add this script to your code and then check If it shows some alert for distance from the coordinates

Comment: Could you please provide a working code snippet? I noticed that in the documentation, I could only find references to gps-new-entity-place and in your code i see you are using gps-entity place and there may be many differences. Thank you

Comment: https://yogeshnain.github.io/ 
Checkout this url, or my repo for complete code

Comment: thank you, now i can see the markers but there is one more problem i encounter right know, they are moving with me, it doesn't seem to take into account the coordinates (lat and long) - i followed the Test Y example

Comment: I am also working on the same issue. I think if we fix the direction of the object along with lat long it will stop rotating around. Let me know if you find some solution

Comment: @dev-982610 i have the same problem with the sample code's.. so your not alone. I am on Android: With some mobile browser the object does not appear, with other mobile browsers the object appears, but always underneath me and follow me. If i will find something i let you know, please do the same
Sample code taken from [here](https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/location-based-aframe/) and [here](https://aframe.io/blog/arjs3/#location-based-ar) (the second one seems to be older)

Comment: I have the same problem where the object keeps moving backward when I walk towards it. I want the object to be fixed and I should be able to walk around it

Comment: Got the same problem, having it not staying on its exact place, does any got a fix on this?

Answer (score 0):

please check https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/issues/558 and see if it helps

I had some problems with this and the issue was that Chrome did not had access to "precise location"

hope stackBot likes this answer now that i found my problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).